# java6: Appending char to a string

Tags: string, performance, character, java-6

Is it better to append a char to a string as compared to adding a string to a string in java6.

Eg. In following two lines of code which one will execute faster:

```
String str = "One" + '\"'
```

or

```
String str = "One" + """
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess String to String concatenation will have little better performance since theirs no need for conversion to Character and calling toString() method on it.

**Java Language Specification:**
15.18.1.1 String Conversion

Any type may be converted to type String by string conversion. 
A value x of primitive type T is first converted to a reference value as if by giving it as an argument to an appropriate class instance creation expression: 
• If T is boolean, then use new Boolean(x). 
• If T is char, then use new Character(x).

...